# Titan GraphDB query within a set

Tags: titan

I have edges that has a property called `type` that stores the different type of relationships between two vertices. The `type` property is a set. I was wondering how can I query to get the edges that contain that type?

**For example:**

Types = [A, B, C] 
Edge1.type = [A, B] 
Edge2.type = [B, C] 
Edge3.type = [A, C]

If I query for edges with type A, I would get Edge1 and Edge3.

Answer (score 0):

Not efficient, but the only way I can think of:

**In TP2:**

```
g.E().filter { it.getProperty("type").contains("A") }
```

**In TP3:**

```
g.E().filter { it.get().value("type").contains("A") }
```